# How does the short story "Big World" from The Turning by Tim Winton explore aspects of Australian Identity?

Tags: short-stories, tim-winton

*[The Turning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Turning_(short_story_collection))* by Tim Winton is a collection of short stories about turnings (obviously) at crucial times in people's lives. I've been asked to read and annotate the first short story in the series – “Big World” – with a focus on its portrayal of personal and cultural aspects of Australian identity (it is an Australian text). Now I haven’t the faintest idea of where to start – in terms of what aspects of Australian identity I should be looking for – but a few ideas would be nice, and I can take it from there and tie the ideas into the text and talk about generic conventions and that side of stuff.

So basically - **What personal and cultural aspects of Australian Identity does "Big World" explore?**

Comment: [This](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2005/apr/02/featuresreviews.guardianreview23) may help you to get started with.